# Bevelled Corner Topology Best Practice

Tags: topology, bevel

Very new to blender and just trying to make sure I don't learn any bad habits, so I'm wanting to understand which of these 4 topologies are best for a bevelled corner like this. I can't remember exactly what I did to get each result but I'm just wondering which I should be aiming for in the future.

Are there any pros/cons to each of these?

Maybe any of them would be ok and no need to worry about it?

(ignore the actual bevel itself, I'm more talking about how it joins to the rest of the mesh)

Corner 1:

[image: Corner1]

Corner 2

[image: Corner2]

Corner 3:

[image: Corner3]

Corner 4:

[image: Corner4]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say enough about your project, if it gives you the result you want in *Rendered* mode then all your solutions are ok, you don't even need all these additional edges, and with right click > *Shade Smooth* and *Normals > Auto-Smooth* option on, you can even get a smooth shape:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But for example if you give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier it may cause some artifacts, even with your edge loops, because it will try to smooth angles that are too orthogonal:

[image]

In that case you need to smooth the shape with more edge loops, bevels are helpful:

[image]

or:

[image]